# Where Could I set the application name user see in home screen

Tags: ios

Where Could I set the application name that user see in home screen, under the application icon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following line to the `InfoPlist.strings` file:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "My Great App";
```

The advantage of this method (as opposed to the entry in `Info.plist`) is that you can provide localized app name for several locales.

Answer (score 5):

Set "Bundle display name" in the Info.plist or your App settings file.
[image]